# While Transforming Table structure columns into a Map object getting "javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

Objective : I am receiving Table data structure in the form of "class java.util.ArrayListobj", I would like to transform into Map (Col Name, Data Type) for later use in generating insert statement

```
Input 
ArrayList data = ['[Field:pack_id, Type:int(9), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]', 
                        '[Field:locn, Type:mediumint(5), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]'] 
Required Output: 
Map =[Field:pack_id, Type:int(9), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]
```

I am receiving error:

> javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1....."

where am I going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    ArrayList data = ['[Field:pack_id, Type:int(9), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]', 
                                '[Field:locn, Type:mediumint(5),Null:NO,Extra:,Default:null,Key:PRI]']      
        
        def lstStrColRec = []
                
        data.each{
                        
            log.info("$it")
            lstStrColRec.add("$it");
            }
        
        log.info(" Column Records List Size :" + lstStrColRec.size())
        lstStrColRec.eachWithIndex{it,i -> log.info("$i : $it")}
                    
        for(i=0; i<lstStrColRec.size(); i++)
            {
                        
            // Split Column Record data into Columns details by splitting on ","
            def lstStrRecColData =[]
            log.info(lstStrColRec.getAt(i))
            lstStrRecColData = lstStrColRec.getAt(i).split(',')
            def mapCol =[:]
            log.info("No of Columns in a Record :" + lstStrRecColData.size())
                            
                for (j=0; j<lstStrRecColData.size();j++)
                    {
                    def lstColSpltData =[]
                    lstColSpltData = lstStrRecColData.getAt(j).split(':')
                    lstColSpltData.eachWithIndex {it,i -> log.info(j +": " +  "$i : $it")}
        
                    if(lstColSpltData[1] !="")
                        mapCol.put(lstColSpltData[0], lstColSpltData[1])
                    else
                        mapCol.put(lstColSpltData[0], Null)
                }
        }
```

Output and error:

```
2022-03-23 18:36:46,671 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: [Field:pack_id, Type:int(9), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]
2022-03-23 18:36:46,671 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: [Field:locn, Type:mediumint(5), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]
2022-03-23 18:36:46,671 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor:  Column Records List Size :2
2022-03-23 18:36:46,672 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 0 : [Field:pack_id, Type:int(9), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]
2022-03-23 18:36:46,672 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 1 : [Field:locn, Type:mediumint(5), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]
2022-03-23 18:36:46,673 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: [Field:pack_id, Type:int(9), Null:NO, Extra:, Default:null, Key:PRI]
2022-03-23 18:36:46,673 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: No of Columns in a Record :6
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 0: 0 : [Field
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 0: 1 : pack_id
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 1: 0 :  Type
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 1: 1 : int(9)
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 2: 0 :  Null
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 2: 1 : NO
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: 3: 0 :  Extra
2022-03-23 18:36:46,674 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:955) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:573) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.arrays.ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod$MyPojoMetaMethodSite.call(ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod.java:60) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at Script91.run(Script91.groovy:113) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    ... 9 more
2022-03-23 18:36:46,675 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Data Sync - Thread Group 1-1
2022-03-23 18:36:46,675 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Data Sync - Thread Group 1-1
2022-03-23 18:36:46,676 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2022-03-23 18:36:46,678 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: I need to transform a binary object `eФзв~G]јХЕЫ\e\/А` to another binary object `8ЭЏWпP2†ЧV%DЙ„C@/ќЋ NІЦЭ$‹u<’®ЗY&[`, please help

Comment: The log `3: 0 :  Extra` tell you that the `Extra:` is only split to 1 element array, as you  can't see `3: 1` on next line. Hence will cause error when calling `lstColSpltData[1]`. Try using [split(':', 2)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) to ensure there are 2 elements in array or check the array size is 2 before accessing 2nd element.

Comment: @samabcde  The split(':', 2)  stmt did the trick. Thank you.